# SublimeHaskell error message on Mac

Tags: macos, haskell, sublimetext3

I'm gettingh following error message when I try to save a .hs file on Mac OS Sierra:

check_lint.run_chain: Cannot execute command chain, hsdev not connected.

I tried to

1. reinstall the plugin
2. Added following  to my subline user settings:

   ```
    {
        "enable_hsdev" : true,
        "enable_ghc_mod" : true,
        "enable_hdevtools": true,
        "add_to_PATH": ["$HOME/.local/bin", "$HOME/.cabal/bin"]
    }
   ```

The syntax checking looks good, but I can't get rid of the message. Any ideas?

Comment: you'd better ask it in sublimehaskell's issues list: https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell/issues

Comment: Have you installed hsdev?

Comment: no, do I need to? I just used sublime package install, as with other languages

Comment: @basile-henry installed hsdev with `cabal install hsdev` from command prompt, restarted sublime and got it working. thanks for the hint